# Jest -UnhandledPromiseRejection TypeError Path must be a string

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, gulp, jestjs

Trying to run jest after installing all the necessary dependencies (npm install/bower install)all the needed packages are in package.json still-I get an error as shown : when I run jest -( I have tried changing the versions of jest )

```
Using Jest CLI v0.7.1
(node:9212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [//path of the file]
```

I tried to run the application : when I run gulp serve I get the following :

```
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

are these two errors related .
Please use the following files for reference:

1) complete source code Im using

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mc3j9k4qetz7dsm/AADOgMl7AQov0BDzhDDvKdzva?dl=0

2) screen-cast of how errors are shown 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v45wlizc47f8kbc/JestAjaxfunction_PromiseRejection.wmv?dl=0

Thanks for any help, 
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

in my case, this error occurred after an update to jest 21.

the fix was in my invocation of jest, including `.` (current directory).

broken: `cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=test node --harmony_proxies node_modules/.bin/jest`

fixed: `cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=test node --harmony_proxies node_modules/.bin/jest .`